# XSL if test string comparison not working

Tags: string, xslt, if-statement

I have some XML this looks like this:

```
<region class="TableInfo">
text
</region>
<region>
text
</region>
```

I want to write XSL that only preserves that part without the class="TableInfo".

I've tried a number of different ways, including:

```
<xsl:for-each select="region[class!='TableInfo']">

</xsl:for-each>
```

and

```
<xsl:for-each select="region">
<xsl:if test="not(class=&apos;TableInfo&apos;)">

</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

and several variations thereof. it seems like it's somehow evaluating as a value rather than a string, because when I set it up as an != test, all the  content gets deleted, and when I set it up as a not(), nothing gets deleted. any help?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:for-each select="region[not(@class='TableInfo')]">

</xsl:for-each>
```

You forgot the @ on `class`, so you were trying to check for class elements instead of the attributes. And apparently the != is not working as well, so I swapped in the not() function instead.

From a stylistic point, I would also suggest looking into using templates that match the region elements so you can use apply-templates instead of a for-each.

Comment: @serilain Did we get the whole picture?  Ruling out only class="TableInfo" lets everything else through.

Comment: That's.. odd. Tested in XsltCake and it didn't work. Could have sworn I did that in my code base. Edited, and a working test is over here: http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/dbiV62

Answer (score 0):

**The identity rule is your friend** (and of course, you need to specify the *attribute* class, not a "class" element):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="region[@class='TableInfo']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML** (fragment wrapped into a single top element to make it a well-formed XML document):

```
<region>
text
</region>
```